# Ajax Call does not respond automatically in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

I am currently working on a dynamically generated accordion with subaccordions. I have implemented a filter function which works perfectly fine. Ajax is used to change the page content. Therefore I have created the following function:

```
function loadSubaccordionContent(elem){
    console.log("loadSubaccordionContent");

    elem = $(elem);
    var accordion_header = $('.ciTypeHeader').closest('.ui-accordion-header-active');
    if(!elem.hasClass("ciTypeHeader")){
        elem = accordion_header;
    };
    var ciTypeId = elem.data("ci-type-id");
    var ciRelationTypeId = elem.data("ci-relation-type-id");
    var sessionId = "accordion_"+ciTypeId+'_'+ciRelationTypeId;
    elem.data("session-id",sessionId);

    ajaxRequest = $.ajax(
        {   url:    '<?php echo APPLICATION_URL?>relation/partial',
            method: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data:   {
                ciRelationTypeId: elem.data("ci-relation-type-id"),
                ciId: elem.data("ci-id"),
                ciTypeId: elem.data("ci-type-id"),
                page: elem.data("page"),
                rowCount: elem.data("row-count"),
                orderBy: elem.data("ordering-array"),
                filterSet: elem.data("filter-set"),
                filter: elem.data("filter"),
                sessionId: elem.data("session-id"),
                layout: false
            },
        }
    ) .done(function( data ) {
        accordion_header.data("filter-set",false);
        return $("#subaccordionContent_"+ciTypeId+'_'+ciRelationTypeId).html(data);
    })
};
```

The problem is, that the $.ajax request is hanging in Firefox. Everything works fine in IE and Google Chrome.

The response only comes back if i do something like a click somewhere in the subaccordion or if I am scrolling.

There is no error message in Firebug -> there I just see that ajax is loading.

In addition if I click on Firebug, I also get the response back.

Has someone ever expirienced a similar behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

trying using the method in the window.onload event.
or use jquery read method at the end.

#### Solution # 1

```
$(function (){
  loadSubaccordionContent()
});
```

#### Solution # 2

```js
window.onload = function loadSubaccordionContent(elem) {
  console.log("loadSubaccordionContent");

  elem = $(elem);
  var accordion_header = $('.ciTypeHeader').closest('.ui-accordion-header-active');
  if (!elem.hasClass("ciTypeHeader")) {
    elem = accordion_header;
  };
  var ciTypeId = elem.data("ci-type-id");
  var ciRelationTypeId = elem.data("ci-relation-type-id");
  var sessionId = "accordion_" + ciTypeId + '_' + ciRelationTypeId;
  elem.data("session-id", sessionId);

  ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo APPLICATION_URL?>relation/partial',
    method: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    data: {
      ciRelationTypeId: elem.data("ci-relation-type-id"),
      ciId: elem.data("ci-id"),
      ciTypeId: elem.data("ci-type-id"),
      page: elem.data("page"),
      rowCount: elem.data("row-count"),
      orderBy: elem.data("ordering-array"),
      filterSet: elem.data("filter-set"),
      filter: elem.data("filter"),
      sessionId: elem.data("session-id"),
      layout: false
    },
  }).done(function(data) {
    accordion_header.data("filter-set", false);
    return $("#subaccordionContent_" + ciTypeId + '_' + ciRelationTypeId).html(data);
  })
};
```

Comment: I tried both solutions, unfortunately ajax is still hanging. When I set the filter the ajax response works. Just the reset is not working. The parameters are correct.

Comment: no there is no error, but I can see that it is loading

Comment: the sequence is: filter - reset filter (this is not working); when i change the sequence: filter - random click -reset filter (this is working). any ideas?

Comment: So you had javascript bugs. if your code is not compiling correctly in browser then this could happen. Now coming to your specific problem, I don't have answer why filter ordering is causing the problem.

Comment: If you have got the solution then please check it as right.

Answer (score -1):

it was a local issue.
I deleted the browser cache and all cookies.
Now it is working.